# Jenkins – Active Choice: AWS ECR Images tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, amazon-ecr

For a parameterized assembly with an image tag selection, I preconfigured the Active Choices plugin in Jenkins
[image]

```
import com.amazonaws.services.ecr.AmazonECR;
import com.amazonaws.services.ecr.AbstractAmazonECR;
import com.amazonaws.services.ecr.AmazonECRClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.ecr.model.ListImagesRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.ecr.model.ListImagesResult;
import com.amazonaws.services.ecr.AmazonECRClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Region;
import com.amazonaws.regions.RegionUtils;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import jenkins.model.*
 
AmazonECR client = AmazonECRClientBuilder.standard().withRegion("eu-west-1").build();
ListImagesRequest request = new ListImagesRequest().withRepositoryName("super-hero-repo");
res = client.listImages(request);
 
 
def result = []
for (image in res) {
   result.add(image.getImageIds());
}
 
return result[0].imageTag;
```

Where, ***"eu-west-1"*** – region where the ECR repository is located;

***"super-hero-repo"*** – the name of your ECR repository;

return list of tags from AWS ECR super-hero-repo

**The problem is the return list of tags NOT by to date** 
*Any help*

Comment: def result = []
    for (image in res) {
       result.add(image.getImageIds());
    }
 
    return result[0].imageTag;

This can be simplified to:

    res.getImageIds().imageTag;

As for listing images by Date, unfortunately I don't think the AWS SDK offers right now.